# How to enforce narrowing to specific type of a typed const in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

My question is whether it is possible to use typeof to infer the actual type of a const variable, independent of the defined wider type?

If you assume that a nested object looks like a tree and the simple properties are leaves. Then I want to have a way to define subtrees.

I want to use this in a Generic that uses `in keyof` and want to iterate only over the explicitly mentioned keys and not over all implied keys by the type definition. In the example below I need that `keyof typeof a` will not include `bar` or `baz`.

#### Example

The idea is that the `Base` type is meant to define the possible structure of the "maximum extend" of variable `a` and allows to use autocompletion when writing `a`.

Once `a` is defined it has its own narrower type which I want and use later to filter certain keys.

```js
type Base = {
    foo?: string;
    bar?: string;
    baz?: string;
}

const a: Base = {
    foo: '123',
};

const a_typeof: typeof a = {
    foo: '123',
    bar: '123', // I want this to be wrong
};
```

I understand that since I defined `a` to be of type `Base` these are equal `type of a == Base`, but I want that `typeof a = { foo: string }` and so `{ foo: string }` narrower type of Base.

Specially, if I remove the `: Base` from the definition of `a` I get the desired effect.

```
const b = {
    foo: '123',
};

const b_typeof: typeof b = {
    foo: '123',
    bar: '123',
//  ^: Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'
};
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBW1AZge3wC4oFgAnASwDsBzAbixwCM5ySyq7GcpWAvDhRoMMAXwwYAxvmpkocEgAU2wSnAA2AHnhIAfFFSZeBYlADkARgBMAZnMAacY2mz5cAPqhI+XCW8QvgqG6EzYpiRWdo5hfGyRNvZOYi4ycsB8IcY4ERaJMSmSafLMXuCBflABQcxZsblRSbGs7HnRyYxAA for an example.

Comment: Typescript is [structurally typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) language. So, as long as `a_typeof` contains all the _mandaory_  elements of `a`, it does not care what extra elements it has. It will think it as a valid `typeof a`

Comment: I edited the description. In a `keyof typeof a` I need this to iterate only over the really written properties (here `foo`) and not over all in `Base`.

Comment: Why cannot you use the second example in your case?

Comment: I would like to use the autocompletion, when I write `a` and this works nicely, when I use the `: Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what you are trying to do from the compiler's point of view:

1. You tell it `a` is of type `Base` to get autocompletion as a side-effect.
2. Then you tell it that `b` has the same type as `a`, which is `Base`.
3. But then you try to tell it that `b` *also* has the same type that `a`'s *value* has.

   Type of `a`'s value is `{ foo: string; }`, which, even if TypeScript allowed you to do that, would mean that `foo` is both required *and* optional. And that is nonsense as far as the type system is concerned.

Now, let's say you are determined to circumvent the above. You can sort of do that with a generic function that returns a *constrained* version of the value you want your autocompletion on:

```ts
const getA = <K extends Base>(a: K) => a;

const a = getA({ foo: "123" });

const a_typeof: typeof a = {
    foo: '123',
    bar: '123', //Error: 'bar' does not exist in type 'Pick<Base, "foo">'
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgq6gMwHtCB%20ALigWACcBLAOwHMBubPKAIzmvMpoZZs8XAF68qdJqywBfbNgDGhelSiMIwAIJRUAHgDSUCAA9gEegBMEsRBAB8ACjgV9ASh12ocaYuWq4Omoamg5oBMQUAEQAjABMAMyRUDKuPlhKKsBeAPqgkIT4FHkQBV6BmDh4RIQUAORx8bUANEK4XNR1Dc1QAPQ9AKLU1IQdULXttVAWhBDW9IRZJrSqDFDFYwAKtAoA1rrwSE1QkdWRdrXYMsxAA)

The generic type parameter ensures autocompletion, while the `Pick` utility type filters the returned type. Although you will get an error you want, nothing stops you from passing, for example, `Base` to the generic type parameter silencing the error.

---

Answering the question "is possible to use `typeof` to infer the actual type of a const variable, independent of the defined wider type?" - no, it is not possible. If you explicitly specified a wider type, it will be used regardless of assignment.

Comment: I think that that "No" actually is the right answer. I realise that the narrow type is correct and I just want auto-complete for creating that type conveniently. So I mixed two different things. Marking this as the correct answer!

Comment: @jhp - upon looking over the answer again, I noticed that the workaround can be made more convenient, resulting in pretty much what you wanted. But you still have to create a function that will just waste space at runtime just to get things working.